# Trouble Making a Graph in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have two columns of data:

**Time Taken**: 00:00:42.1093750, 00:00:09.5468750, 00:00:47.2656250,  00:01:27.6718750
**Start Time**: 21:02:27, 21:33:16, 22:03:27, 22:34:19

I want to make a cluster graph from the two columns so that the "Start Time" will be on the x-axis and the "Time Taken" will be on the y-axis.
I've tried to do so myself but the graph came out blank or not even close to what I wanted.
Best case I got an backwards graph where the axes were reversed, but replacing the columns didn't work.

Can someone please try to make this graph on their computer and tell me how to do so?

Comment: You're probably going to have to convert all those numbers into decimals instead of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a quick shot at this. Is this close to what you are trying to do? I converted your 'Time taken' column to duration in seconds and used an XY graph.

[image]

Hope this is heading in the right direction for you.

Comment: thanks, sorry for the late response. i just found out that my question is here and not in stackoverflow, anyway this is what i did too, thanks for the answer again!

Comment: BTW, what is the difference between superuser.com and stackoverflow.com?

Comment: I think stackoverflow is for programming questions.